# Port forwarding on local network

Tags: networking, ip, port-forwarding, isp

My router is forwarding both ports 80 & 443 to my Linux (Ubuntu 16) box...and everything works great.

To access my Linux box from my laptop (Windows 7) I only have to type in my public IP address and...whether my laptop is connected to the same router as the Linux box or not...I am able to connect all the same.

My question is:

If my laptop is on the same local network as my Linux box and I connect by using the public IP address (not the local one), will the connection be routed via the ISP?

PS

I'm not sure whether this question belongs on servefault or superuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

via ISP, no.

The router will show that public IP as locally connected to the wan interface on your router, the packets will never leave that device and be returned back to your local IP.

You can think of this similarly to accessing your computer at 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.0.10 (as example, your computer is at 192.168.0.10)